# How can I install pygame for Python 3 on Debian jessie?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, debian

I tried many times to install pygame for Python 3.5, but never succeeded.
For example, I tried [this](https://heritagerobotics.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/compiling-pygame-for-python-3-2-in-xubuntu/) but got the following error:

```
$ python3
>>> import pygame
enter code hTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
>>>
```

Everything looks fine while building and installing, but I still don't see any changes. Did I forgot something? Is there something wrong?

Comment: did you try to install with `pip3 install pygame` ? It works for me on Linux Mint which is based on Ubuntu, which is based on Debian. BTW: yesterday I updated PyGame to 1.9.3

Comment: Of course I tryed, but this time it worked 0,0 How did you do that? I swear I tryed for 1 year, I never got the solution, and BAM,this is the first attemp I did and now it works...
Do you solve all the problems like that? Because if you do I have a huge list :)

Comment: as I know pygame author made new package 6 months ago as Sprint at EuroPython - you can even see news on PyGame page: http://www.pygame.org/news.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pygame
```

The problem was that, at the time, pygame wasn't packaged yet. This is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on debian 8 and I upgraded pip:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I have installed pygame using the code from [Pygame website](http://pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation):

```
python3 -m pip install pygame --user
```